# caught signal when session leader sends SIGHUP to process groups

Tags: c, session, signals

When a terminal disconnects, kernel will notify controlling terminal by sending a `SIGHUP` to it. After that, controlling process sends `SIGHUP` to all processes in the same session. What happens when those processes catch the `SIGHUP` but do some other thing instead of terminating in signal handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They go on with their business and terminate

- When they decide
- When they receive another signal